# how can i get a date from user in android

Tags: android

hi i want to let the user to open a Calendar and chose day.
i try [this guy code](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/datepickerdialog) .
but it didnt worked.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(currentDateString);
}
```

Comment: android studio is an IDE, meaning it just helps you code. if your question is about android, please use the android tag unless you specifically want to ask a question regarding the android-studio IDE

Comment: can you give more detailes please? prove classes of your activity and fragments

Comment: to be honest i didnt understand what he did.

Comment: @zgames, I have published some solution, can you try it please? assign my method to your btn or another ui element which you will click :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For working with DatePickerDialog you can also use such code:

```
private void callDatePicker() {

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                         // handle some date
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

you can call this method from button click. I don't sure whether we have to use also some fragments for such functionality. But I also have just seen this video and this solution also looks workable. You can also use [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog) for better understanding.

Comment: if I answered on your question, can you please apply this solution as corent via pressing on tick on its left side :)

Comment: you answered my question:).
by the way where did you learned this?

Comment: I didn't understand you :) What did you mean with this question? I have some developer experience so maybe it came from it :D

Comment: just want to know.
because i want to be able to do it myself...